# SASS child styles not being applied to JSX element

Tags: reactjs, sass, jsx

I'm working with a react template that leverages SASS and am trying to change the styles on the home page. It leverages a `<gutter>` component that allows the CMS user to modify sizing but the home page is unique. So for a short-term approach I reached for styles in this component and was surprised that this wasn't working.

Here are the current styles of `index.module.scss` of the gutter component:

```
.gutterLeft {
  padding-left: var(--gutter-h);
}

.gutterRight {
  padding-right: var(--gutter-h);
}

.home {
  .gutterLeft {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  
  .gutterRight {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}
```

Here is the JSX of the gutter component:

```
import React, { forwardRef, Ref } from 'react';

import classes from './index.module.scss';

type Props = {
  left?: boolean;
  right?: boolean;
  className?: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  ref?: Ref<HTMLDivElement>;
};

export const Gutter: React.FC<Props> = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, Props>((props, ref) => {
  const { left = true, right = true, className, children } = props;

  return (
    <div
      ref={ref}
      className={[left && classes.gutterLeft, right && classes.gutterRight, className]
        .filter(Boolean)
        .join(' ')}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
});

Gutter.displayName = 'Gutter';
```

Here is the output HTML in the browser:

```
<div class="home"
   <div class="Gutter_gutterLeft__PHEQH Gutter_gutterRight__cwFWD HighImpact_hero__uC6pf"
      <!-- other children -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You probably need to define the class `home` as a global class, because I can see that the other classes are processed as css modules, adding hashes.
`:global(.home) {  .gutterLeft {  ... }  .gutterRight { ... } }`

Comment: @Martin yep that did it, feel free to post that as the answer so I can mark it as correct.